# What is the difference between RTCA and EUROCAE standardisation?

Tags: radar, mode-s

We know that RTCA and EUROCAE working to develop standards for international civil aviation (air surveillance systems)

My questions are:

- Do RTCA and EUROCAE work together for air surveillance standards or RTCA  for airborne  equipment like Mode S transponder and EUROCAE for ground station like ADS-B GS/MSSR-S ?
- What is the EUROCAE standards documents for the MSSR-S Radar?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, EUROCAE and RTCA do work closely together when there is an interest of both European and American industries to standardise something in a certain area.

Typically this would be the case for airborne equipment such as transponders.

Specifically in the surveillance domain there are these combined  Working Groups (EUROCAE) / Special Committee's (RTCA):

- Mode-S - WG49 & SC-209
- ADS-B - WG-51 & SC-186
- Traffic Alert and Collision Avoidance Systems (TCAS) - WG-75 & SC-147

The EUROCAE Mode-S standard is found in ED-73F (MOPS for Secondary Surveillance Radar Mode S Transponders), the RTCA equivalent is DO-181F. These two documents have basically the same content.

The ground element of Mode-S (i.e. a MSSR-S radar) is not specified in an EUROCAE standard, but instead it is a standard published by Eurocontrol:
[EUROCONTROL Specification for
European Mode S Station (EMS)](https://%20https://www.eurocontrol.int/sites/default/files/2021-09/eurocontrol-ems-spec-ed-4-0.pdf)